# Creative Exchange Live Gulp task "No Gulp file"

Tags: sxa, gulp, creative-exchange

I've exported the site through the Creative Exchange export and followed the configuration steps to have it working on Visual Studio Code through readme.md file in the folder.
Calling 'gulp watch-gulp' throws "No Gulp file".

I already run the npm install steps and no luck.
Copying gulpfilebabel.js from the Basic2 theme to the root of my theme makes it run but it throws an error about syntax.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when the Creative Exchange exports the theme files, it exports the `gulpfile.babel.js` file without the `.` between `gulpfile` and `babel`. A period is normally an invalid character for an item name, so that was probably stripped when the file was added.

If you rename the file to have the period back in (`gulpfile.babel.js`), gulp will then be able to find the Creative Exchange tasks.

#### Caution

Be careful when using the Creative Exchange Import process, this will sometimes delete the `gulpfile.babel.js` file, and it can also throw an error because of the multiple periods in the file name. Its always good to make sure you have a backup of that file, or keep it source controlled and don't commit any changes.

Answer (score 2):

The Creative Exchange Import process deletes the gulpfile.babel.js (since a dot is not a valid character for the item name).

**Workaround**

From Sitecore support I got the tip to rename the 'gulpfilebabel'-item to 'gulpfile' and  change the extension from 'js' to 'babel.js'. And that works for me, the item was not deleted anymore.